# Speeding up this function?

Tags: performance-tuning

Is there a way to speed this function?

```
SpeedthisUpPlease[{\[Beta]_, \[Delta]_, \[Theta]_, \[Rho]_, 
   aPar_, \[Gamma]_, \[Eta]_}] := 
 Block[{L1, L2, K11, K12, K22, S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6, MatPi, W, U, 
   Cmat, CmatStar},
  
       
  L1 = (\[Eta] - \[Beta]*(1 - \[Delta]))/(\[Beta]*\[Eta]*\[Theta]^2);
  L2 = \[Rho]*(\[Eta] - \[Beta]*(1 - \[Delta]))/(\[Eta] - \[Beta]*(1 \
- \[Theta])*(1 - \[Delta]));
  K11 = (\[Eta] - \[Beta]*(1 - \[Theta])*(1 - \[Delta]))/(\[Beta]*\
\[Eta]*\[Theta]);
  K12 = (\[Beta]*\[Eta]*\[Theta]^2 - \[Eta] + \[Beta]*(1 - \
\[Theta]^2)*(1 - \[Delta]))/(\[Beta]*\[Eta]*\[Theta]^2);
  K22 = \[Eta]*\[Theta]/(\[Eta] - \[Beta]*(1 - \[Theta])*(1 - \
\[Delta]));
  S1 = (K22 - K11)/K12;
  S2 = ((K22 - K11)*L1 - K12*L2)/(K12*(K11 - \[Rho]));
  S3 = K22;
  S4 = K12*
     L2/(K22 - 
        K11) + ((K22 - \[Rho])*((K22 - K11)*L1 - K12*L2))/((K22 - 
         K11)*(K11 - \[Rho]));
  S5 = {1 - (1 - \[Theta])/\[Theta]*S1, 
    S1 + (\[Eta]/\[Beta] - 
         1 + \[Delta])/(\[Theta]^2*(\[Eta] - 
           1 + \[Delta]))*(\[Theta] - S1), 1 - 1/\[Theta]*S1};
  S6 = {1/\[Theta] - (1 - \[Theta])/\[Theta]*S2, 
    S2 + (\[Eta]/\[Beta] - 
         1 + \[Delta])/(\[Theta]^2*(\[Eta] - 1 + \[Delta]))*(1 - S2), 
    1/\[Theta] - 1/\[Theta]*S2};
  
  U = Transpose[{Flatten[{S5, S1}], Flatten[{S6, S2}]}];
  MatPi = {{S3, S4}, {0, \[Rho]}};
  (*W={{0},{1}};*)
  
  ysteady = 
   aPar^(1/(1 - \[Theta]))*(\[Theta]/(\[Eta]/\[Beta] - 
         1 + \[Delta]))^(\[Theta]/(1 - \[Theta]))*(1 - \[Theta])/\
\[Gamma]*(1 - \[Theta]*(\[Eta] - 1 + \[Delta])/(\[Eta]/\[Beta] - 
           1 + \[Delta]))^-1;
  
  csteady = (1 - \[Theta]*(\[Eta] - 1 + \[Delta])/(\[Eta]/\[Beta] - 
          1 + \[Delta]))*ysteady;
  
  hstead = (1 - \[Theta])/\[Gamma]*(1 - \[Theta]*(\[Eta] - 
           1 + \[Delta])/(\[Eta]/\[Beta] - 1 + \[Delta]))^-1;
  
  
  Cmat = Drop[U, {2}];
  CmatStar = {{Log[ysteady]}, {Log[hstead]}, {Log[csteady]}};
  
  {MatPi, Cmat, CmatStar}
  ]
```

The input must be a list of 7 real numbers, most of them will be between 0 and 1, but not all.
Below is an example of a possible input.

```
vec = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[1], 7] // Flatten
```

The output of `SpeedthisUpPlease[vec]` is the following:

```
{{{0.531418, 0.931421}, {0, 0.454912}}, {{0.325754, 
   1.14853}, {-0.132494, 0.249482}, {0.458248, 
   0.899051}}, {{-0.623107}, {0.0943832}, {-0.547928}}}
```

MatPi is the 2 by 2 matrix `{{0.531418, 0.931421}, {0, 0.454912}}`.

Cmat is  the 3 by 2 matrix `{{0.325754, 1.14853}, {-0.132494, 0.249482}, {0.458248, 0.899051}}`,

CmatStar is the 3 by 1 matrix `{{-0.623107}, {0.0943832}, {-0.547928}}`.

Regarding an explanation about the function itself, it's the solution of a state-space model, whose formula has been derived by hand. The input are the parameters of this state-space model.

Comment: Probably, but readers should not have to figure out what it's supposed to do because there's no explanation, nor examples of input, timings, etc., nor just what constitutes fast enough in "faster"...

Comment: @ciao you're completely right. I'm sorry... It'll take me a while to improve the question... see you soon.

Comment: @ciao I hope it's better/good enough now.

Comment: Seems pretty fast to me! but if you need it to be faster, you do seem to be doing a lot of numerical computations. have you tried `Compile`-ing it?

Comment: @thorimur I've tried, but I didn't manage to get it working... Compile is a tough nut to crack for me... =D